# C++ use a while loop to count the number of characters a user inputs

Tags: c++, stdin, eof

Write a program that asks for text input from the keyboard. The output of this program should be the amount of characters, the amount of words and the amount of newlines that have been typed. Multiple consecutive spaces should not be counted as multiple words.

The reading of characters from the keyboard can be stopped when the shutdown-code ^D (CTRL + D) is entered

And my code is:

```
int main()
{
    char a;
    int characters = 0;
    int words = 1;
    int newlines = 0;
printf("Input something\n");

while ((a = getchar())!=4)
{
    if (a >= 'a'&&a <= 'z' || a >= 'A'&&a <= 'Z')
        characters++;
    else if (a = ' ')
        words++;
    else if (a = '\n')
        newlines++;

}
printf("The number of characters is %d\n", characters);
printf("The number of words is %d\n", words);
printf("The number of newlines is %d\n", newlines);


return 0;
}
```

I know that ^D has the ASCII-value 4, but after I used (a=getchar())!=4 and input some words and ^D on the screen, and press 'enter', the program didn't show anything. Could someone help me please.

Comment: Because it is a c++ homework, I think the basic knowledge of C and C++ is similar

Comment: Not at all @Yifan

Comment: Alright, maybe because I am a newbie, could you tell me why my code is incorrect

Comment: The question asks that multiple consecutive spaces should not be counted as multiple words. In my code I couldn't make multiple consecutive spaces as a single space.

Answer (score 2):

The key point about handling <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> that the question does not state, is that keystroke is the EOF (end of file) indicator for console programs. This means that when you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, `getchar()` does not return 4, but returns the special value `EOF`.

Note that the value `EOF` is not a value that can fit in a `char` variable, so you have to declare `int a` instead of `char a`:

```
int a;

while ((a = getchar()) != EOF)
```

Comment: Thank you Greg, I tried your code just now. But under this circumstance, if I run this program and input something,I cannot jump out of the loop(whatever I input, the screen did not show the result such as the amount of words)

Answer (score 1):

By definition, EOF has no ASCII value. K&R tells us

> `getchar` returns a distinctive value when there is no more input, a
>   value that cannot be confused with any real character.

So you have to compare against the symbolic constant EOF. Its value is one which lies outside the range of valid ASCII codes.

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

Also, `c` must be an `int`, not a `char`; this way, EOF fits.

Another issue in your program is your use of `=` (assignment) instead of `==` (comparison). You write `else if (a = ' ')` but mean `else if (a == ' ')`.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried EOF and int c, but I don't know how to end inputting. Whatever I input, the screen did not show the result such as the amount of words. Even though I pressed the 'enter', it just starts a new line.